# OTP : export isochron

Tags: java, opentripplanner

I would like to export my isochrones with this link: `http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/npdc/isochrone?fromPlace=50.44748389174579,2.973716363690387&mode=WALK,TRANSIT&date=09-14-2021&time=8:00am&maxWalkDistance=500&cutoffSec=1800&cutoffSec=3600`
but nothing happens, nothing downloads.
Do you have any ideas ?

Here is what JAVA returns to me :

> {"type":"FeatureCollection","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}},"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[2.9697,50.4475],[2.9699,50.4469],[2.9703,50.4457],[2.9702,50.4453],[2.9701,50.4439],[2.9703,50.4435],[2.9709,50.4428],[2.9717,50.4426],[2.9737,50.4427],[2.9748,50.4428],[2.9765,50.4429],[2.9786,50.4439],[2.9794,50.4445],[2.9803,50.4457],[2.98,50.4461],[2.9794,50.4467],[2.9782,50.4468],[2.9783,50.4475],[2.9773,50.448],[2.9765,50.4491],[2.976,50.4489],[2.9763,50.4493],[2.9765,50.4494],[2.9784,50.4511],[2.9775,50.4517],[2.9765,50.4523],[2.9738,50.4511],[2.9737,50.4511],[2.9735,50.4511],[2.9709,50.4502],[2.9705,50.4493],[2.9703,50.4489],[2.9697,50.4475]]]]},"properties":{"time":3600},"id":"fid--60d73e63_17be43c1e35_-7ff7"},{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[2.9697,50.4475],[2.9699,50.4469],[2.9703,50.4457],[2.9702,50.4453],[2.9701,50.4439],[2.9703,50.4435],[2.9709,50.4428],[2.9717,50.4426],[2.9737,50.4427],[2.9748,50.4428],[2.9765,50.4429],[2.9786,50.4439],[2.9794,50.4445],[2.9803,50.4457],[2.98,50.4461],[2.9794,50.4467],[2.9782,50.4468],[2.9783,50.4475],[2.9773,50.448],[2.9765,50.4491],[2.976,50.4489],[2.9763,50.4493],[2.9765,50.4494],[2.9784,50.4511],[2.9775,50.4517],[2.9765,50.4523],[2.9738,50.4511],[2.9737,50.4511],[2.9735,50.4511],[2.9709,50.4502],[2.9705,50.4493],[2.9703,50.4489],[2.9697,50.4475]]]]},"properties":{"time":1800},"id":"fid--60d73e63_17be43c1e35_-7ff8"}]}

in my computer console :

> 14:47:37.640 INFO (SPTWalker.java:156) SPTWalker: Generated 65719 points (0 dup edges, 0 no geometry) from 12889 vertices / 33044 states.
> 14:47:37.641 INFO (AccumulativeGridSampler.java:139) Added 411 closing samples to get a total of 748.
> 14:47:37.641 INFO (SampleGridRenderer.java:89) Computed SPT in 52msec, 27msec for sampling (79 msec total)
> 14:47:37.643 INFO (IsoChroneSPTRendererAccSampling.java:101) Computed 2 isochrones in 2msec

Thank you !
Have a nice day,